# What is the origin of neutrino mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, higgs

Standard model shows zero mass for neutrino and seesaw model explains why the neutrino mass is so small. But to show that the neutrino mass is small, the mass should be originated by some mechanism. If this mechanism is not higgs mechanism then what is it? Kindly please provide the mathematical calculations associated with it.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because the link describes and gives links for where we  are with the mass of the neutrino